# Ubuntu 9.10 desktop installation via USB (boot)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, installation, boot

I have made a live boot USB using the UnetBootIn tool for Ubuntu 9.10.  I have Windows XP SP2 installed as the primary OS, and want to make a partition for Ubuntu.  However when I try to boot it via USB, it just goes to the boot menu of Ubuntu, then I enter the default type for installation.  After that nothing happens, just the Ubuntu logo shows up and just that nothing happens after that.

I can try the simpler task also i.e. install via CD but I want to know what's not working with this USB boot method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick tuto for Ubuntu USB installation. Pretty sure you can find something to help you to dual boot your system.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Also, take a quick read at this site to guide you correctly thru your installation.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth taking a look at wubi - this lets you install Ubuntu from within XP without creating a partition or changing XP's boot process.